# Not able to run sample "BookShelf" Java App Engine app

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to run appengine for Java project by following steps mentioned in https://cloud.google.com/java/getting-started/using-forms?authuser=3

To run the app on local machine I gave the command:

```
mvn -Plocal clean jetty:run-exploded -DprojectID=[YOUR-PROJECT-ID]
```

But I am getting following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid storage type. Check if bookshelf.storageType property is set.
        at com.example.getstarted.basicactions.ListBookServlet.init(ListBookServlet.java:62)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:637)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initialize(ServletHolder.java:421)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:744)
```

I tried the same thing GCP Shell but I got the same exception. 
What could be going wrong here?

**snippet of web.xml**

```
 <!-- [START config] -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>bookshelf.storageType</param-name>
        <param-value>${bookshelf.storageType}</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

**snippet of pom.xml**

```
  <properties>
    <!-- [START config] -->
    <projectID>myProjectID</projectID> <!-- set w/ -DprojectID=myProjectID on command line -->

    <bookshelf.storageType>datastore</bookshelf.storageType>   <!-- datastore or cloudsql -->

    <sql.dbName>bookshelf</sql.dbName>                        <!-- A reasonable default -->
<!-- Instance Connection Name - project:region:dbName -->
<!-- -Dsql.instanceName=localhost to use a local MySQL server -->
    <sql.instanceName>${projectID}:us-central1:${sql.dbName}</sql.instanceName>
    <sql.userName>root</sql.userName>                         <!-- A reasonable default -->
    <sql.password>myRootPassword1234</sql.password> <!-- -Dsql.password=myRootPassword1234 -->
    <!-- [END config] -->
```

Please clarify.
Thanks.

Comment: You might want to check your pom.xml and web.xml files. In pom you should have <bookshelf.storageType> property set to either datastore or cloudsql. Check that that value is than populated in web.xml

Comment: bookshelf.storageType seems to be defined and used properly in pom.xml and web.xml. Updated the post with snippets from both the files.

Comment: Try to follow what is specified in this link: 
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/issues/302  
                                                                                                         
1.Follow this first: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/blob/master/bookshelf/README.md                                                   
2. Try to change the param-value in your web.xml file: Replace <param-value>${bookshelf.storageType}</param-value> with <param-value>datastore</param-value>.

Comment: Above workaround fixes the exception. Thanks.

Comment: But getting new exception: com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException: Unauthenticated.
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.v1.HttpDatastoreRpc.translate(HttpDatastoreRpc.java:129)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.v1.HttpDatastoreRpc.translate(HttpDatastoreRpc.java:114)
    at com.google.cloud.datastore.spi.v1.HttpDatastoreRpc.runQuery(HttpDatastoreRpc.java:182)

Comment: I have updated pom.xml with following properties:

Comment: Is there anything else I am missing here? Thanks.

Comment: Your new error seems to be related to Authentication issues. Did you follow the part related to Enabling API's and Creating Web Credentials that is in the second link that i sent you before?: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/blob/master/bookshelf/README.md

Comment: Also related to the first issue is being followed in here: https://issuetracker.google.com/68086679

Comment: @VictorGGl First issue related with storage type seems to be fixed in Github repo now.

Comment: Regarding, second issue of "Unautheniticated" exception, I have followed the procedure to enable the list of APIs, creation of OAUTH2 credentials, and updation of the same in pom.xml. But getting still the same exception.

Comment: @Omkar In which pom.xml file are you including your credentials? The changes which are mentioned here https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/tree/master/bookshelf refer to the pom.xml file in the folder getting-started-java/bookshelf/

Comment: @VictorGGl, I have updated pom.xml file in getting-started-java/bookshelf/pom.xml location. Still the same error :(

Comment: Also, raised a bug in GitHub at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java/issues/351

Comment: @Omkar Which credentials are you using in the machine where you are running the app? If you run the command "gcloud init" you should be able to choose the account you would like to use with gcloud commands. Check that this account has enough permissions (in this case Datastore permissions and Storage. You can see the roles granted for your service account in https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/quickstart). Please do not share here any of that information, as it'is private and sensitive information.

Comment: @Omkar I don't think this is a bug, I don't get your error. If my previous comment didn't solve your problem, maybe better post a new more detailed question here in stackoverflow with your problem and copy the link here in a new comment.

Comment: @VictorGGl sure... thanks

Answer (score 1):

This issue was due to an error in Github repo (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/getting-started-java).
 It is solved now. If you run into this, update to the last version of the repo.